# toggle only works when double clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click my links using the onmousedown event  I have to double click them for them to toggle. I am not understanding why this is so.

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x) {
//the 'x' variable represents the add friend/message container value
        if($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
        //if the container is hidden then we will slide it down and show it
            $('#'+x).slideToggle(400);

        } else {
            //if its not being hidden then we will hide it
            $('#'+x).hide();
        }
        //this just means we have to hide all the containers
        $('.interactContainers').hide();
}
```

I'm calling it from this div

```
<div class ="interactionLinksDiv">
           <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('add_friend');">Add Contact</a>
</div>          
<div class ="interactContainers" id ="add_friend">
  <div align ="right"><a href="#" onclick= "return false" onmousedown = "toggleInteractContainers('add_friend')">cancel</a></div>
                Add as a contact? &nbsp;
  <a href ="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:addAsFriend(); ">Yes</a>  
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors which is frustrating. I'd greatly appreciate it if I was told why this happened and what I could do to prevent it from happening again. Any programming tips along the way would be awesome as well.

Comment: Script stop working altogether @cale_b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo** Minor changes done: http://jsfiddle.net/FGqE7/

Please let me know if I missed anything!

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x) {
    //the 'x' variable represents the add friend/message container value
    if (!$('#' + x).is(":visible")) {
        //if the container is hidden then we will slide it down and show it
        $('#' + x).slideDown(400);

    } else {
        //if its not being hidden then we will hide it
        $('#' + x).hide();
    }
    //this just means we have to hide all the containers
   // $('.interactContainers').hide();
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried redoing this in jsFiddle. It's a little complicated since we don't have more details.

HTML:

```
<div class ="interactionLinksDiv">
    <a href="#" class="toggleInteractContainers" data-target="add_friend">Add Contact</a>
</div>          
<div class ="interactContainers" id ="add_friend">
  <div align ="right">
      <a href="#" class="toggleInteractContainers" data-target="add_friend">cancel</a></div>
  Add as a contact? &nbsp;
  <a href ="#" class="addAsFriend">Yes</a>  
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".toggleInteractContainers", function() {
        target_id = $(this).data("target");
        $('#' + target_id).slideToggle(400);
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".addAsFriend", function() {
        // Do something here when someone clicks on Yes 
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kj4rK/

Basically, here's a few notes.

- You are using jQuery, you should not be using events directly in the DOM (do not use onmouseclick="" inside  tags). You should be using proper bindings and/or delegations functions included in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/on/
- .toggle() and .slideToggle() always do the opposites of their states: if they are hidden, it will show, if it's visible, it will hide. Your code did not work because you had conditionals (If it's hidden, toggle it --- instead of If it's hidden, show it) http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/